# `&` in badge name is displayed as `&amp;` in the notification

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notification-bar

Because a picture is worth a thousand words:

[image: You've earned the "Strunk & White" badge]

Should that not be *You've earned the "Strunk & White" badge* rather than the *"Strunk &amp; White"* badge?

Comment: That duplicate target seems appropriate for the question. I don't see any **answer** there though.

Comment: True, but bugs take time to fix. Sometimes few minutes, sometimes few hours and sometimes months or years for low priority bugs.